# Executing program on server-side with ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an executable file that works fine by hand locally. It converts a file to another new file by some parameters. I'm using ASP.Net and that executable installed win2003 server 
sp2. I can use it from local but, I can't execute the program from a web browser using system.diagnosting.process. When I use that, I can see the process in task manager with user name "NETWORK SERVICE", and it won't dissappear without ending process by hand and won't work.

I tried impersonation, try as a web service, edited local policies, apply all privilages, etc...

Is there any suggestions about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an app pool in IIS. Assign it the local account ('by hand locally') . Assign the application to this newly created app pool and see if it works.

You can also use [procmom](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)  to see why the original process hung under "NETWORK SERVICE", probably registry access or something else.